# (Python) Best way to filter specific terms in a string?

Tags: python

I have a script that fetches information from the internet. To cut a long story short, I end up having a variable that contains a string. Based on this string I have programmed the script to decide whether to discard or further process the information that the string pertains to based on if:

- there's a particular word
- or couple of words in a specific order within the string.

I would like to know what the best algorithm is to achieve this efficiently and with a good if not 100% correct accuracy.

Currently I have the following code (massively reduced to just include the specific portion; there are normally loops around this, etc, etc):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
def findWord(z):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(z), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

filterList = [
              "term-1","term-2","term-n"
             ]
uncleanString = "This! is* a test [string],.}".lower()

#Remove all punctuation
for c in "!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>,.'":
    cleanString = uncleanString.replace(c, "")

#Check if the words in filterList are present, if not then process further
no = 0
for word in filterList:
    result = findWord(filterList[filterList.index(word)])(cleanString)
    if result == None:
        pass
    else:
        no = 1
        break

    if no == 0:
        #then do further processing here, e.g.
        print(cleanString)
        #reset condition (when implementing code in loop(s)
        no = 0
```

In my actual script my filterList is large. It's a slow script and takes around 30 mins to complete though I think this is more due to the platform I'm running it on (RPi and not PyPy either), the communication with the internet (BS4/HTTPlib), and interaction with a MySQL database... Do you have any ideas on how I can speed this portion up before I move onto refining other sections or would you say the above is adequate?

Answer (score 0):

make a single large regular expression with alternates.

```
reg=re.compile(r'\b('+"|".join(filterList)+r')\b')
```

Looks like this

```
\b(term-1|term-2|term-n)\b
```

You do not have to loop over the term items, they are all in one regexp

Call it once on the compiled object, instead of "findWord" call

```
reg.search
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make it more readable, certainly:

```
if not any(word in cleanString for word in filterList):
    # further processing
```

This cuts out the string formatting and regex compiling step.